# Hadoop/Impala equivalent for Oracle dba_tab_partitions

Tags: hadoop, impala

Is there a meta table in Hadoop/Impala that collectively stores partition information for all the tables like dba_tab_partitions in Oracle

Comment: do you have access to hive/impala metastore? if yes. you can see tables there. Otherwise you need to create a shell or py scripts to create a table like this.

Comment: Yeah, I do have access to Hive metastore and found a bunch of SYSTEM tables that arent accessible directly via IMPALA, Is there a way we can expose it at the IMPALA layer. Currently, the SYSTEM tables as I understand are in another MariaDB Database. (Sorry my terminologies might be out of whack here, still learning)

Comment: you can get those tables into Impala/hive using sqoop and direct DB access - then  you can use it. This will be easier approach

Comment: Thanks, @KoushikRoy, Do you have a link to the steps/procedure I can use to set it up

Comment: First pls ensure you have sqoop tool and jdbc driver for mariadb. here is a sample sqoop statement - `sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:mariadb://xxhost/myexample" --username mariadb --password mariadb  --table mariatable --target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/hivetable --hive-import 
 --hive-table hive_mariatable --hive-overwrite --delete-target-dir --m 1 `

Comment: Thanks, mate - Just to confirm, so this will be an offline copy of the hive metastore table, right?

Comment: yes, offline and depends on schedule of sqoop. But if you schedule sqoop every hour, then it will be hourly copy.